# Ionic/Angular 2 transferring data from parent to child UI issue

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm working on the browser starting an Ionic/Angular 2 project and for some reason I need to click an arrow to see data I pass from a parent component/page to a child component/page.  The name of the child component is "Details". I pass the "Details" page an object from the "Directory" page. I intend for the pattern to mirror the Ionic 2 tutorial project where data is passed from the list page to the item-details page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/tutorial/

**directory.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Details } from '../details/details';

@Component({
  selector: 'directory',
  templateUrl: 'directory.html'
})
export class Directory {
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.offer = {test: "Perfect Attire", test1: "Perfect Attire"}
}

toDetails(event, offer){
    this.navCtrl.push(Details,{
      offer: offer
    });
  }
}
```

**directory.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
   <button ion-button round large (click)="toDetails($event, offer)">
      toDetails
   </button>
</ion-content>
```

**details.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import  Lodash from 'lodash';


@Component({
  selector: 'details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html'
})
export class Details {
  selectedItem: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    // If we navigated to this page, we will have an item available as a nav param
this.selectedItem = navParams.get("offer")

}
}
```

**details.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>CashPass Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="selection">
    {{selectedItem.test}}
  </div>
    {{selectedItem.test1}}
</ion-content>
```

At this point I expect to just see the data on the page "Perfect Attire" but for some reason I need to click the arrow next to "Details". What's going on?

**First I need to click this!**

[image]

**But I should see this when I come to the Details page without having anything to click!**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector can not be 'details'. I changed it to 'detail' and everything worked as normal. I guess 'details' is a magic word somehow. I'm not sure why or what happened there.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'detail',//'detail' not 'details' makes everything work normal!
  templateUrl: 'details.html'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The first page with the details button should be your directory.html
In directory.ts file you are pushing the Details page to your navigation controller.

```
    toDetails(event, offer){
    this.navCtrl.push(Details,{
      offer: offer
    });
  }
```

Which shows the Details page (Your details.html button click event must be calling toDetails).
If you need to see details page directly , you will have to set

```
RootPage=Details
```

in your app.component.ts
and send offer data to it through other means like a provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see how to make a fix based on what you suggested. I added the directory.html for your view. What I don't understand is why I would need to tamper with the root page. Following the tutorial example link listed in my question you'll see the list.ts (parent) does not need to tamper with the root page to get the data to show straight away for item-details.html (child). Because of this I don't see why I need to tamper with the root page and if so how I might do that on the fly.

Comment: Is the details button shown twice? Once for directory.html and another for details.html?

Comment: no the details button is only on the directory page. Is there something more specific you want to elaborate on. I want to make sure I'm clear.

Comment: ok..I am not sure what is the issue.. You have directory as root page with a gotoDetails button. In your directory ts on click  it opens details page with the data

Comment: yes, it opens the page with the data but it just inexplicably doesn't show it but it requires you to do the extra click to see the data.